# Proving this property of logical equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to know if

$$(p\equiv 1)\not\equiv(p\equiv 1)\tag{1}$$

is logically equivalent to

$$(p\equiv 1)\equiv(p\not\equiv 1)\tag{2}$$

$\forall p$, where $\equiv$ means logical equivalence and $p$ is a WFF.

I just don't know where to start.

EDIT:

For clarity, I supose the question can be phrased as:

> Saying that "$p$ is always true" is not equivalent to "$p$ is always true" is logically equivalent to saying "$p$ is always true" is equivalent to "$p$ is never true".

Comment: Not clear.......

Comment: $(p \equiv 1)$ means "$p$ is always *true*".

Comment: Two formulas are *logically equiv* when they have the same truth values for every interprettaion.

Comment: $(p \not \equiv 1)$ means that $p$ is not always *true*.

Comment: Thus, $(p \equiv 1)$ and $(p \not equiv 1)$ are **not** logically equiv.

Comment: $(p \not \equiv 1)$ is $\lnot (p \equiv 1)$ that reads "$p$ is **not always** true".

Comment: But "not always true" means "sometimes false" and **not** "always false".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $q\equiv(p\equiv 1)$ and $(1)$ and $(2)$ are logically equivalent, then it should be true that

$$(p\not\equiv p)\equiv(p\equiv\lnot p)$$

Clearly, the LHS is always false, as well as the RHS, so both statements are logically equivalent, both are false statements.